# Using i18n module at rendering a jade template with app.render and not res.render

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, cron, pug

**Environment**:

Node.js, Express, i18n Module, Jade

**Purpose**:

Render an internationalized jade template for email it, and given a "locale" property such as "es_ES".

**Description**:

I have a mailing object that sends mails which language is based on a user.locale property, so given a 'es_ES' value i want to send a jade rendered template in the given language.

For i18n i make this at the express initialitation:

```
app.use(i18n.init);
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    i18n.setLocale(req.getLocale());
    next();
});
```

So when i use res.render i just do the next thing at the jade template:

`#{__('key')}`

This works great, but i have a cron that doesn't have a req, just the locale in a property of the user object and when i try to render the jade template as above but changing res.render for app.render:

```
/*** Module Dependencies ***/
var mandrill = require('mandrill-api/mandrill');
var mandrill_client = new mandrill.Mandrill(g.wizco.mandrill_api_key);

/**
 *  MAILER API
 */

var mailer = {


    send_activation_mail: function(user, cb){
        var self = this;
        app.render('mails/account_confirmation_email', {var1: 'Holaaaaaaa'}, function(err, html){
            if(err) { console.log(err); return err }
            self.send_mail(html, 'Activación de cuenta', user.email, user.displayName, cb);
        }); 
    }

.....

}
```

i get the next error when rendering the jade template:

> undefined is not a function

Meaning __('...') which is the i18n shortcut for i18n module.

Answer (score 1):

I just required the i18n module and set the locale to the user's one:

```
/*** Module Dependencies ***/
var mandrill = require('mandrill-api/mandrill');
var mandrill_client = new mandrill.Mandrill(g.wizco.mandrill_api_key);
var i18n = require('i18n');

/**
 *  MAILER API
 */

var mailer = {


    send_activation_mail: function(user, cb){
        //app.render('mails/account_confirmation_email')
        var self = this;
        i18n.setLocale(user.locale);
        app.render('mails/account_confirmation_email', {layout: false, var1: 'Holaaaaaaa', __: i18n.__}, function(err, html){
            if(err) { console.log(err); return err }
            self.send_mail(html, 'Activación de cuenta', user.email, user.displayName, cb);
        });
    }

.....
```